# Ajax Response to create autocomplete box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Ajax Response to the dropdown autocomplete and respone is like this

{ "consignmentList" : [ "" , "AAA" , "ABC" , "BHU" , "MAN" , "WER" , "ZXC"]}

and now i want to fetch all if through loop and display in the ul field in list format.

```js
function autocomplet() {
  var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
  var consignmentID = $('#consignmentID').val();
  var consignmentList = $('#consignmentList');
  if (consignmentID.length >= min_length) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/jqueryreturn',
      type: 'POST',
      datatype: JSON,
      data: {
        consignmentID: consignmentID
      },
      success: function(data) {
        consignmentList.show();
        consignmentList.html(data);
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('#consignmentList').hide();
  }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item) {
  // change input value
  $('#consignmentID').val(item);
  // hide proposition list
  $('#consignmentList').hide();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label style="margin:15px 0 0 0;">Consignment:</label>
  <input onkeyup="autocomplet()" id="consignmentID" type="text" class="inputlt" name="consignmentId" value="${(consign._id)!" "}" id="c" style="font-size: 16px " onclick="clearInput(this)">
  <ul id="consignmentList"></ul>
```

Comment: You could have better use jQuery choosen plugin for this purpose. It's an easy to use plugin.

Comment: Best jQuery autocomplete plugins list http://www.sitepoint.com/10-ajaxjquery-autocomplete-tutorial-examples/